# DNS failover with Docker Swarm 1.12

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm

I want to setup a failover for a webservice I've written.
Everywhere i read that docker swarm 1.12 does automatic failover but I think only for failed containers.

**How should i configure public DNS for my service?**

**How does failover work if a host is down?**

With normal dns round robin and IPs of the nodes it won't work. every nth request will fail for n servers. The docker route mesh doesn't help if one host is down. Or do i miss something here?

FYI: Currently I'm not using docker swarm but I'm planing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You got a couple of options:

- If you are using a cloud provider like amazonaws, you can use ELB or what ever loadbalancer your cloudprovider provides, They usually support mode TCP and healthchecks. Then you will point your dns to load balancer. This way when ever a node fails, it will be removed from load balancer via healthchecks and will be back when it is healthy again.
- You can use your own load balancer. HAproxy and Nginx support TCP mode and you can set healthcheck rules. when ever a node fails, it will be removed from load balancer via healthchecks and will be back when it is healthy again. Make sure HighAvailablity is provided via tools like keepalived so the loadbalancer wont become a point of failure.

Please note this applies to TCP traffic as many loadbalancers dont support UDP traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I'm using your 2nd option. But here I have the same problem. What is when the node (were one of the loadbalancer containers run) is down? What can i do here? I something like updating DNS round robin?